# Paperclip not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can't seem to run paperclip although I already have it as a plugin in my vendor/plugins folder. I'm getting this error on my command "ruby script/generate paperclip upload_grade file"

```
`gem_original_require': no such file to load -- rails/generators/active_record (MissingSourceFile)
```

UPDATE1: I can't seem to install paperclip as a gem, paperclip 2.7

UPDATE2: I have solved it by installing paperclip 2.3

Thanks for the answers guys.

Comment: What rails version are you using? 2.x?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Rails 2.3 and you probably are not using bundle you need to initialize paperclip:

```
# In config/environment.rb
...
Rails::Initializer.run do |config|
  ...
  config.gem "paperclip", :version => "~> 2.4"
  ...
end
```

Also make sure you use a version compatible with your rails version. Take a look at the [documentation](http://rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/2.7.0) and follow the procedures.

Also you have a Screencast on PaperClip: http://railscasts.com/episodes/134-paperclip

Comment: It seems that it requires me to use ruby version 1.9.3. I'm currently using ruby 1.8.7

Comment: @fujisan in the Readme it says: "If you're still on Ruby 1.8.7 or Ruby on Rails 2.3.x, you can still use Paperclip 2.7.x with your project."

Comment: I'll install it and give you feed back after. Thanks

Comment: Why am I having this error:

ERROR:  Error installing paperclip:
 activesupport requires Ruby version >= 1.9.3.

Comment: @fujisan check this link: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/pull/1270 You'll need to build the gem manually.

Comment: @fujisan You can build a gem using these comands:

`gem build paperclip.gemspec`

`gem install paperclip`